# Como substituir todos valores de uma determinada tabela no MYSQL de uma vez?

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma tabela (`produtos`) que tem a coluna `product_params`

Varios produtos estão com o valor dessa tabela com `max_order_level=""` e quero substituir todos para `max_order_level="1"`, ou seja, trocar o valor vazio de max_order_level para 1.

Há uma forma que eu possa fazer isso tudo de uma só vez?

Comment: Qual é o tipo da coluna?

Comment: ela é varchar(255)

Comment: Update produto set max_order_level="1"; se quer fazer isso em todos os produtos da tabela não precisa de where.

Answer (score 1):

Sim. Deve haver várias, aqui está uma delas:

Você pode usar a **função** [`REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) (não confundir com o **comando** [`REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replace.html)) no update. Ela vai te retornar a string original completa, somente com a parte procurada substituída.

Assim:

```
UPDATE produtos
    SET product_params = REPLACE(product_params, 'max_order_level=""', 'max_order_level="1"')  
WHERE product_params LIKE '%max_order_level=""%'
```

A única restrição seria que o produto tivesse esse parâmetro definido como você espera (`max_order_level=""`), só para reduzir a quantidade de registros afetados para os que o serão efetivamente.

[**Veja esse exemplo funcionando no sql fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d396d8/1)