# Remover parte de texto dentro de coluna no MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Preciso remover um código de HTML que consta dentro de uma tebela no banco de dados.

No caso o nome da tabela é OBS, e dentro dela tem um texto normal dentro de um **p** e também outro **p** com o seguinte código:

```
<p><a target="_blank" href="/uploads/docs/58e7a4fd05ca6.pdf "><img alt="" style="width: 175px; height: 45px;" src="/uploads/imagens/59d292393a88f_900x.jpg" /></a></p>
```

Gostaria de remover todo esse **p** por um espaço em branco. Manter o conteúdo dentro de **p** desde que não seja esse **a**.

O nome da tabela é PRODUTOS e a coluna é OBS. Como ficaria a sintaxe?

Comment: Você quer ficar só com as _tags_? Apagar tudo? Não ficou muito claro pra mim

Comment: Eu respondi ali, mas lendo o questionamento do @rLinhares realmente surgiram algumas dúvidas: o conteúdo dentro desse *P* é variádo em cada registro (ou seja, referenciam links e imagens diferentes)? Nessa coluna existe uma cadeia de elementos encadeados que incluem vários ***P*** e você quer remover somente o **P** mais interno?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considerando a resposta de [@Diego](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/78713/diego-rafael-souza) (que foi a que mais se aproximou do meu entendimento) e o comentário sobre a *tag* ter um valor variável, utilizaria o seguinte código:

```
UPDATE produtos SET obs = ' ' WHERE obs LIKE '<p>%</p>'
```

Com isso, `obs` seria *"zerado"* apenas quando seu conteúdo fosse referente à *tag* `<p>`.

Answer (score 3):

#### Caso seja um trecho de texto fixo:

Se for puramente substituição de texto será o mesmo problema que eu [respondi aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/300987/como-substituir-todos-valores-de-uma-determinada-tabela-no-mysql-de-uma-vez/301014#301014).

Usa a função [`Replace`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) para substituir essa parte do conteúdo.

Ficaria assim:

```
UPDATE produtos
    SET obs= REPLACE(obs, '<p><a target="_blank" href="/uploads/docs/58e7a4fd05ca6.pdf "><img alt="" style="width: 175px; height: 45px;" src="/uploads/imagens/59d292393a88f_900x.jpg" /></a></p>', '')  
WHERE obs LIKE '%<p><a target="_blank" href="/uploads/docs/58e7a4fd05ca6.pdf "><img alt="" style="width: 175px; height: 45px;" src="/uploads/imagens/59d292393a88f_900x.jpg" /></a></p>%'
```

#### Caso o conteúdo de **P** seja variável

Você pode utilizar uma combinação de `SUBSTRING` com `INSTR`:

```
UPDATE produtos
    SET obs = SUBSTRING(obs, 0, INSTR(obs,'<p>')) + SUBSTRING(obs, INSTR(obs,'</p>'))
WHERE obs IS NOT NULL AND 
      INSTR(obs, '<p>') >=0 AND
      INSTR(obs, '</p>') >=0
```

O [`SUBSTRING`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_substr) na sintaxe `SUBSTRING( str, inicio, quantidade)` vai retornar [`quantidade`] caracteres a partir da posição [`inicio`] da string [`str`]
Já na sintaxe `SUBSTRING( str, inicio )`, a função retorna todos os caracteres de [`str`] a partir da posição [`inicio`].

A função [`INSTR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_instr) - `INSTR( str, strProcurada)` -  um valor maior ou igual a zero correspondente ao índice da posição inicial da string `str` onde é encontrado o texto `strProcurada`.

#### Caso existam vários *P* aninhados na coluna e você quer remover um específico

Você poderá fazer a substituição a partir de expressões regulares ([`REGEXP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp)). Mas para respodermos especificamente, teríamos que saber qual a estrutura básica do código onde está procurando.

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

Utilize a função [`Replace`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_replace.asp):

```
UPDATE PRODUTOS SET
    OBS = REPLACE(OBS, "<p><a target=\"_blank\" href=\"/uploads/docs/58e7a4fd05ca6.pdf \"><img alt=\"\" style=\"width: 175px; height: 45px;\" src=\"/uploads/imagens/59d292393a88f_900x.jpg\" /></a></p>", "");
```

A função `replace` é responsável por substituir uma parte de uma `string` por outra.

Caso esse seja todo o conteúdo do seu campo, pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
UPDATE PRODUTOS SET
    OBS = ""
WHERE OBS = "<p><a target=\"_blank\" href=\"/uploads/docs/58e7a4fd05ca6.pdf \"><img alt=\"\" style=\"width: 175px; height: 45px;\" src=\"/uploads/imagens/59d292393a88f_900x.jpg\" /></a></p>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que os valores devem mudar de registro para registro, mas se for apenas para apagar o conteúdo da coluna, um `update sem where` serve.

```
update PRODUTOS set OBS=' '
```

Isso vai apagar todos os valores da coluna OBS e trocar por um espaço `' '`, se quiser trocar por **nada**, usa `''`

```
update PRODUTOS set OBS=''
```